# How can I stop config transformation inserts being inserted twice?

Tags: asp.net, continuous-integration, teamcity, web-config-transform

Like most people I'm using teamcity as a CI tool and I'm also using web config transformations quite heavily, a lot of times to insert config values.

My build process is generally to build the entire solution and then (using msdeploypublish) deploying the website to a website.

Because I'm running msbuild twice, the config transformations are being run twice and so I'm ending up with duplicate values in the final versions of the config files (mainly web.config but I have others as well).

Is there a way to only run the config transformations the one time, for example by using a parameter in msbuild that will stop it from happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found the slightly undocumented `InsertIfMissing` which seems to do the job.

Comment: I actually ran into this with a normal web.config transformation. Suddenly today when I preform the same publish I did yesterday, the Inserts are executing twice. WTF! Luckily this fixed it, through I shouldn't have had to need it. Thanks!

Comment: I saw this same issue with a regular web.config transform. It turned out to be due to a bad Configuration|Platform mapping in my `.sln` file. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31542753/web-config-transform-is-running-twice-on-publish/31542754