# Web.config transform is running twice on publish

Tags: asp.net, .net, msbuild

I have a solution that includes three web projects (as well as a lot of class library projects). The web projects all use Web.config transforms to specify per-environment configuration.

I have Web.config transforms for multiple build profiles, named Web.UAT.config, Web.Staging.config and Web.Release.config

I am building and deploying the project from my CI server using MSBuild with the following arguments:

```
/t:Clean,Build /p:Configuration=UAT;DeployOnBuild=True;PublishProfile=UAT
```

For exactly one of the three projects, the web.config transforms appear to get applied twice, with elements marked `xdt:Transform="Insert"` appearing twice. Looking in the build output, it seems that all three projects run the following targets:

```
PreTransformWebConfig
TransformWebConfigCore
PostTransformWebConfig
PreProfileTransformWebConfig
```

But the problematic project also runs these targets (immediately after those listed above):

```
ProfileTransformWebConfigCore
PostProfileTransformWebConfig
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `.csproj` files for web projects include the following by default:

```
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
```

This file in turn imports `\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets`, also under the VSToolsPath (on my dev machine, this corresponds to `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\VisualStudio\v12.0`).

The interesting segment of this file looks like the following:

```
<ProjectProfileTransformFileName Condition="'$(ProjectProfileTransformFileName)'=='' And '$(PublishProfileName)' != '' ">$(_ProjectConfigFilePrefix).$(PublishProfileName)$(_ProjectConfigFileExtension)</ProjectProfileTransformFileName>

<!--if $(TransformWebConfigEnabled) is also enabled and the ConfigTransform and ProfileTransform happen to have same filename, we default $(ProfilefileTransformWebCofnigEnabled) to false so it doesn't do double transform-->
<ProfileTransformWebConfigEnabled Condition="'$(ProfileTransformWebConfigEnabled)'=='' And '$(TransformWebConfigEnabled)' == 'true' And ('$(ProjectProfileTransformFileName)' == '$(ProjectConfigTransformFileName)')">False</ProfileTransformWebConfigEnabled>
```

The double transform was happening as a result of `ProfileTransformWebConfigCore` running, which is conditional on `ProfileTransformWebConfigEnabled`, which only defaults to false if the `ProjectProfileTransformFileName` and `ProjectConfigTransformFileName` are equal.

I added the following target to all three of my projects:

```
  <Target Name="DebugWebConfigTransform" AfterTargets="PreProfileTransformWebConfig">
    <Message Text="ProjectProfileTransformFileName: $(ProjectProfileTransformFileName)"/>
    <Message Text="ProjectConfigTransformFileName: $(ProjectConfigTransformFileName)"/>
  </Target>
```

For the problematic project, this target output the following:

```
DebugWebConfigTransform:
  ProjectProfileTransformFileName: Web.UAT.config
  ProjectConfigTransformFileName: Web.Release.config
```

Since these two values were different, the double transform was occuring for the reasons described above.

The reason the ProjectConfigTransformFilename was set to Web.Release.config was that the `ProjectConfigurationPlatforms` in my `.sln` file was incorrect. The `.sln` file's Configuration|Platform pair of `UAT|Any CPU` was being mapped to `Release|Any CPU` for this project.

I think it was actually applying the UAT *and* Release transforms as a result (due to the exact nature of my transforms and the order in which they were applied, this was indistinguishable from applying the UAT transform twice).

Updating the `ProjectConfigurationPlatforms` mapping in the solution file resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was occurring for me because I had multiple projects in my solution configuration using different configurations.

It was running more than one web.config transforms because of this configuration:

[image: Configuration Manager]

After switching the projects to use the same configuration I no longer received the issues in my web.config.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this can also happen if you leave off the Configuration msbuild parameter. The PublishProfile isn't good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I had a different issue than all the answers. In my case, I had a profile named `staging.pubxml` which was using the configuration `prod`. On publish both the `staging` and the `prod` transformation would occur.

Turns out, the name of the `.pubxml` file also triggers a transform if the same configuration can be found. I simply changed the name of the file and it solved my issue.